# What feature detector to choose and how to access to the feature points data

Tags: opencv, matching

I would like to know which detector would be the best to do the following task:
I have two images of a same room taken from a different point of view along the X axis, the camera is not tilting during the translation.

I would like to match a point/ area of the first image to the second one and determine how much pixels would separate those. (from the initial position to the other)
I know that there are plenty of feature detector in OpenCV, and i would like to use one of the fastest and accurate to do this task. 
I can have access to the depth values by the way, but I would like to only use the rgb data (in gray scale) to find matching points and determine the distance separating those in pixels.

Could you advise me on this?
Thank you a lot.

Comment: Would this help? http://www.morethantechnical.com/2012/02/07/structure-from-motion-and-3d-reconstruction-on-the-easy-in-opencv-2-3-w-code/

Comment: seems very promising I will take a look at that! thanks!

Comment: Why not try each detector/descriptor pair and choose the one that works best for your samples?

Comment: do you have a suggestion according to what I have written so far?